# Wird or werden in sentences starting with „es“

Tags: verb-usage

I am working through a German grammar practice and cannot understand why these two examples of Futur I are not the same:

> Es werden viele neue Arbeitsplätze entstehen.
>
> Es wird allen Bürgern besser gehen.

Both sentences start with "es" and both refer to a plural, so why is  "wird" used in one sentence and "werden" in the other?

Answer (score 4):

### Short Answer

> The subject of the second  sentence is *es* and of the first *Arbeitsplätze*. Thus the main verbs do conform with the corresponding subjects.

The following deals with explaining the presence of *es* in both cases. They  may be viewed as representing two very different phenomena.

### Second sentence

This is just a variation of

> Es geht jemandem gut. / Someone is well.

You can regard the *es* here as fulfilling the need for a subject in the sentence. Similar to English

> It rains.

Or even better the *it* in:

> How is it going?

You notice that in the first highlighted sentence *es* does not care about case and number of *jemandem*. Rather, *es* is a placeholder, like *it* in the English sentence. Therefore you may say:

> Es geht Papa gut (masculine)
>
> Es geht Mama gut (feminine)
>
> Es wird den Bürgern besser gehen (neuter plural)

```
*Es* is the *sentence subject* placeholder and doesn’t *refer* or 
*point* to *Papa/Mama/Bürgern* in the above sentences!
Nevertheless, *es* is the sentence subject to which the verb in each 
sentence — *geht/geht/wird* — conforms.
```

What I explained here for *es geht jemandem gut* similarly holds for *es gibt*, *es ist kalt*,...

> Es gibt keine Drachen. / There are no dragons.
>
> Es war der Jungfer kalt./ The miss was feeling cold.

### First sentence

By permuting the parts of the sentence while  *omitting es* you can see that *es* is not explained likewise here (i.e. it is not replacing a missing, grammatically required  subject). You could permute it into a legitimate sentence without *es* in the following way:

> Viele neue Arbeitsplätze werden entstehen.

This straightforward sentence order usually emphasises *viele*. Your sentence order was chosen to convey a different emphasis (it could be an item in an enumeration of clauses). But why does it contain *es*?

Foreign language learners books on German sentence structure and [Wikipedia on German sentence order](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_sentence_structure)  love to include a rule similar to this one:

> The conjugated verb is the second element in the main clause and the last element in the subordinate clause.

Teachers using this rule will say the *es* is there so that *werden* is in the second place. They will then teach you to view “viele neue Arbeitsplätze” as one chunk (subject and modifiers), so that their rule also covers:

> Viele neue Arbeitsplätze werden entstehen.

```
   *Es* makes sure the sentence structure is idiomatic 
   and does not *point* to  Arbeitsplätze!
   *Arbeitsplätze* in turn is the sentence subject, 
   to which werden conforms.
```